# Raycaster didn't detect the whole geometry in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
function checkCollisiontofloor() {
     
    
        var cube = scene.getObjectByName('floor');
        var originPoint = cube.position.clone();

        for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < cube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
            var localVertex = cube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
            var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(cube.matrix);
            var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(cube.position);

            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
            var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(cubearr);
            if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
                   limit++;
                console.log(limit);
                collisionResults[0].object.visible = false;
                if (limit == num)
                    {
                        createCubes(num+=5);
                        level++;
                        var l = "level";
                        var final = (l + "  " + level);
                        console.log (final);
                        document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = final;
                        speed+= 0.1;
                    }
            }
        
    }
    }
```

The Whole Code

```
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<script src="lib/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<html>
    <style>
        #myText2
        {
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        .buttons
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
            <label style="color:red;"><span id="myText2"></span></label>
            <h1>Score: <span id="myText"></span></h1>
            <h1> <span id="Level"></span></h1>
        </div>

<script>
    var ww = 1500,
    wh = 500;
    var scene;
    var k=0.02;
    var Up=60;
    var count=0;
    var flag = true;
    var speed=0.4;
    var cubearr = [];
    var num = 10;
     var max=48 , min=-48;       
    var limit = 0;
    var level = 1;
function init()                              
{
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(ww, wh);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, ww/wh,1,1000);
    camera.position.z =  100;
    camera.position.y = 5;    
    camera.name = 'cam';
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    scene.add(camera);

    
    light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1, 10000 );
    light.position.set( 0, 20, 50 );
    light.name = 'light';
    scene.add( light );  

    text();                               
    createCubes(num);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSphere);
    dir();
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
};
function text()
{
    //THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
    elements = new THREE.Object3D();
    loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    loader.setPath( 'C:/xampp/htdocs/graphics/' );

 

    // Create sphere
    sphereG =  new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
             
    spherem = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff2255});

    texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('spheretex.jpg');
              
    material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereG, material2);
           
    sphere.position.y = -13;

    sphere.name = 'sp';

    elements.add(sphere);

    //Create floor
    planeG = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 5, 10 );
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
    texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('texturefloor.jpg');
    texture1.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture1.repeat.set( 100, 10 );
    material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1 } );
    //texture msh shaghl fa hatet material bas msh material1 3ashn ahtulu color
    floor= new THREE.Mesh( planeG, material1 );
    floor.position.y = -20; 
    floor.name = ("floor");
    elements.add(floor);
    scene.add(elements);         
    //renderer.render(scene,camera);
            
}; 
function createCubes(x)
{
    document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = "Level 1";
    geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,5,5);
    texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '25649.jpg' );
    materialtex = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
   
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++)   
    {
        cubearr[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, materialtex);
        cubearr[i].position.x =(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        cubearr[i].position.y = Up;
        Up = Up+10;
        scene.add(cubearr[i]);
        
        //cubes.push(cubearr[i]);
        
    }
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
} 
function dir() 
{
    var s = scene.getObjectByName("sp");
    if (flag == false)
    {
        return;   
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(dir);
    sphere.position.y +=speed;
    camera.position.y +=speed; 
    floor.position.y+=speed;
    checkCollisiontosphere();
    checkCollisiontofloor();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
function moveSphere(e)                 
{
    moveDistance = 0.30;
    sp = scene.getObjectByName('sp');
    cam = scene.getObjectByName('cam');
    light = scene.getObjectByName('light');
    if (e.keyCode == '39') 
    {
        if(sp.position.x < 48)
        {
            sp.rotation.z -= moveDistance;
            sp.position.x += 3;
            sp.rotation.x += 3;
            light.position.x += 3;
            count++;
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = count;
        }
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == '37')   
    {
        if(sp.position.x > -48)   
        {
            sp.rotation.z += moveDistance;
            sp.position.x-= 3;
            sp.rotation.x -= 3;
            light.position.x -= 3;
            count++;
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = count;
        }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == '27')
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = true;
            dir();
        }
    }     
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSphere);

function checkCollisiontosphere() {

    
        var cube = scene.getObjectByName('sp');
        var originPoint = cube.position.clone();

        for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < cube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
            var localVertex = cube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
            var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(cube.matrix);
            var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(cube.position);

            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
            var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(cubearr);
            if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
    document.getElementById("myText2").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
            flag=false            }
        
    }
}

    function checkCollisiontofloor() {
     
    
        var cube = scene.getObjectByName('floor');
        var originPoint = cube.position.clone();

        for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < cube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
            var localVertex = cube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
            var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(cube.matrix);
            var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(cube.position);

            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
            var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(cubearr);
            if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
                   limit++;
                console.log(limit);
                collisionResults[0].object.visible = false;
                if (limit == num)
                    {
                        createCubes(num+=5);
                        level++;
                        var l = "level";
                        var final = (l + "  " + level);
                        console.log (final);
                        document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = final;
                        speed+= 0.1;
                    }
            }
        
    }
    }

    


             
function levels()
 {
     if(count == 30)
     {
        document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = "Level 2";
        speed=0.6;
     }
     if(count == 60)
     {
        document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = "Level 3";
        speed=0.8;
     }
     if(count == 90)
     {
        document.getElementById("Level").innerHTML = "Level 4";
        speed=1;
     }
}  
init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible code? and error?

Comment: It doesn't have syntax error or exception it is a logical error just run the code and check the console while the falling boxes touch the floor it doesn't detect collision at the edges

Comment: You should invest more time and provide a proper live example like: https://jsfiddle.net/rz6293L8/. When doing so, you will notice that your code loads textures from local paths which breaks the visuals of the live example. Your code does also not work with the latest version of `three.js` (r125) since it depends on `THREE.Geometry`.

Comment: In general, performing collision detection with raycasting is very inefficient and not reliable. You should work with bounding volumes instead. Besides, instead of animating camera, floor and sphere, you should animate the cubes. Right now, the logic in your app is very confusing.